# How do I return multiple column from a nested select in postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery, sql-returning

I have a postgresql query that looks like this:

```
      update service_requests
      set service_request_status = 'Rejected', modified_on = now()
      where service_request_id = $1 and service_request_status = 'Submitted'
      returning 
        (select service_request_id, service_request_status, requestor_id
        from service_requests
        where service_request_job_uuid in
          (select service_request_job_uuid from service_requests where service_request_id = $1)
        )
```

I'm getting an error: subquery must return only one column

But I need to return at least three: service_request_id, service_request_status, requestor_id. And they need to be returned from a group of records to which the one being updated belongs.

The idea is this: a user submits a service request to one or more 'pros' as we call them. These pros bid on the service request. There is a row in the database for each pro and they are grouped together by the service_request_job_uuid column. In the case where a pro rejects the service request, this query is run. We want to return all records corresponding to this service request to see if there any other pros who have not yet rejected the service request.

But if I can't select multiple columns in the first nested select, how do I return the information I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
with upd as (
    update service_requests
    set service_request_status = 'Rejected', modified_on = now()
    where service_request_id = $1 and service_request_status = 'Submitted'
    returning service_request_id 
)
select service_request_id, service_request_status, requestor_id
from service_requests sr
where exists (
    select 1 
    from service_requests sr1
    inner join upd u on u.service_request_id = sr1.service_request_id 
    where sr1.service_request_job_uuid = sr.service_request_job_uuid
)
```

Or, maybe:

```
with upd as (
        update service_requests
        set service_request_status = 'Rejected', modified_on = now()
        where service_request_id = $1 and service_request_status = 'Submitted'
        returning service_request_job_uuid 
    )
select sr.service_request_id, sr.service_request_status, sr.requestor_id
from service_requests sr
inner join upd u on u.service_request_job_uuid = sr.service_request_job_uuid
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. I created this modified version of your query: with updated_request as (
          update service_requests
          set service_request_status = 'Rejected', modified_on = now()
          where service_request_id = $1 and service_request_status = 'Submitted'
          returning service_request_job_uuid) select sr.service_request_id, sr.service_request_status, sr.requestor_id, service_request_job_uuid from service_requests sr where sr.service_request_job_uuid = updated_request.service_request_job_uuid But now it tells me: missing FROM-clause entry for table "updated_request"

Comment: @gib65: why are you modifying the query I provided, doesn't it produce the result you want?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just gives me the record I updated. I need ALL records belonging to the group defined by service_request_job_uuid.

Comment: @gib65: I think we might be able to simplify this. See my updated answer.